# Call function attribute from outside function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call input attribute value from child function.

Code is Here:

```
     $("input.ups").fileinput({
         uploadUrl: "/imalatci/products/uploadimages",
         allowedFileExtensions: ["jpeg","jpg", "png", "gif"],
         maxImageWidth: 500,
         maxImageHeight: 400,
         maxFileCount: 5,
         resizeImage: true,
         language:"tr",
         uploadExtraData: function() {
             return {
                 product_id: $(this).attr('product_id')
             };
         }
     }).on('filepreupload', function() {
         $('#kv-success-box').html('');
     }).on('fileuploaded', function(event, data) {
         $('#kv-success-box').append(data.response.link);
         $('#kv-success-modal').modal('show');
     });
```

I want to get $("input.ups") product_id attribute in this function:

```
uploadExtraData: function() {
                 return {
                     product_id: $(this).attr('product_id')
                 };
             }
```

But it is getting `undefined` error?

How can we fix this ?

Comment: Inside the `uploadExtraData` the `this` reference will not be the element which raised the event. You should declare a variable with the data you require in the outer scope to use within that handler. You haven't shown a full example of your code, so I can't tell you exactly how to do this.

Comment: This is full jquery code really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of `this` within the `uploadExtraData` function is not the `input.ups` element which the plugin is being instantiated on. To achieve what you require you would need to loop over them individually so you can get a reference to the element. Try this:

```
$("input.ups").each(function() {
    var $input = $(this);
    $input.fileinput({
        uploadUrl: "/imalatci/products/uploadimages",
        allowedFileExtensions: ["jpeg","jpg", "png", "gif"],
        maxImageWidth: 500,
        maxImageHeight: 400,
        maxFileCount: 5,
        resizeImage: true,
        language:"tr",
        uploadExtraData: function() {
            return { product_id: $input.attr('product_id') };
        } 
    }).on('filepreupload', function() {
        $('#kv-success-box').html('');
    }).on('fileuploaded', function(event, data) {
        $('#kv-success-box').append(data.response.link);
        $('#kv-success-modal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

I would also suggest using a `data-*` attribute instead of a non-standard attribute like `product_id`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved my day

Comment: No problem, glad to help.